# Getting the unique word count from each row in a pandas column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, unique

I am pretty new to Python and trying to preprocess some text data for my NLP project on hiphop lyrics.
I have a column in my dataframe with (already cleaned) lyrics and want to make another column containing the length of the unique words in the lyrics column for each artist.

This is my dataframe.tail()

[image]

I only managed to make a set of unique words with this code.

unique_words = set()

unique_wordsDF['clean_lyrics1'].str.lower().str.split().apply(unique_words.update)

print(unique_words)

I know I somehow have to put the set method into a for loop to iterate over all the songs but cannot seem to figure it out how to do it. My desired output would be to have a 'unique_count' column based on the number of unique words inside the 'clean_lyrics1' column

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop here:

```
df['n_unique_words'] = [len(set(x.split())) for x in
                        df['clean_lyrics1'].str.lower()]
```

How it works:

- convert the column to lowercase with [`str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html)
- for each values `x` in the column, `split` the string into words, keep the unique values with a `set` and get the length of the set with `len`.

Comment: can you provide a real minimal example as text?

Comment: I believe this worked! Could you explain the code to me please?

Comment: I added some details, let me know if anything is still unclear ;)

Comment: It explains it! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope your problems solve...

```
text_file = open('data.txt', 'r')
text = text_file.read()

#cleaning
text = text.lower()
words = text.split()
words = [word.strip('.,!;()[]') for word in words]
words = [word.replace("'s", '') for word in words]

#finding unique
unique = []
for word in words:
   if word not in unique:
      unique.append(word)

#sort
unique.sort()
print(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
dataframe['unique_words'] = dataframe['clean_lyrics1'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x.split(' '))))
```